Solution to heat equation on disk with boundary condition oscillating in time
I am trying to solve analytically the heat equation $\partial_t u = \Delta u$ on the unit disk $D_1\subset\mathbb{R}^2$ with Dirichlet boundary condition $e^{ikt}$.  That is, I want a solution satisfying for all $x^2+y^2=1$
$$
u(x,y,t) = e^{ikt}.
$$
I believe that by radial symmetry and time translation invariance the solution should have the form
$$
u(x,y,t) = f(x^2+y^2) e^{ikt}.
$$
When I plug in this ansatz into the heat equation itself, I obtain:
$$
\Delta u(x,y,t) = (4 f'(r^2) + 4r^2 f''(r^2)) e^{ikt} = \partial_t u(x,y,t) = 
ik f(r^2) e^{ikt}
$$
so that leads to the following ordinary differential equation for $f$:
$$
4sf''(s) + 4f'(s) = ik f(s).
$$
I don't think this ODE has a nice analytical solution (at least, not that Wolfram Alpha could find).  Is that correct?  Or did I make a mistake and have I derived the wrong ODE?

I think your Laplacian is incorrect. You should get this and the resulting equation will be a Cauchy-Euler equation

@whpowell96 You may notice that I am using $r^2$ as the radial coordinate rather than $r$, which (I think) is why the formula doesn't match what you have in the link.  Nevertheless if I do use this formula I get an equation of the form $g'' + g'/r = ik g$ which is still not a Cauchy-Euler equation.  Perhaps you can elaborate about the resulting Cauchy-Euler equation and how to solve it? I might be stubbornly missing something simple.

I think your ODE is correct and I think it has not a nice analytical solution.
However, by an Ansatz with a modified Bessel function I get
$$
f(s):=\frac{4}{ik} \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(n!)^2}\left(\frac{ik}{4}\right)^n s^n 
$$
as a solution:
$$
ikf(s) = 4 \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(n!)^2}\left(\frac{ik}{4}\right)^n s^n
$$
$$
f'(s)= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n}{(n!)^2}\left(\frac{ik}{4}\right)^{n-1} s^{n-1} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{n+1}{((n+1)!)^2}\left(\frac{ik}{4}\right)^n s^n
$$
$$
sf''(s)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n(n-1)}{(n!)^2}\left(\frac{ik}{4}\right)^{n-1} s^{n-1} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(n+1)n}{((n+1)!)^2}\left(\frac{ik}{4}\right)^{n} s^{n} 
$$
Since
$$
\frac{(n+1)n}{((n+1)!)^2} + \frac{n+1}{((n+1)!)^2} - \frac{1}{(n!)^2}= 0
$$
the function $f$ satisfies $4sf''(s)+4f'(s)-ikf(s)=0$. Note that $f$ is related to the modified Bessel function $I_0(x)$, see here About modified Bessel Function of first kind with order zero?
One should check  that $f(1) \not= 0$. If so, then the desired solution should be
$$
u(x,y,t)= \frac{f(x^2+y^2)}{f(1)}e^{ikt}
$$
